# What is the difference direct descendent (>) vs. descendant in jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

What's the difference between these two jQuery statements? They seem to do the same thing by getting all the children div tags.

```
$("#mainblock div")
```

```
$("#mainblock > div")
```

Comment: I disagree with this question being closed as "too narrow." Everyone uses jquery these days and I bet the majority of users could not give you the answer to this question. How is that too narrow/localized?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`$("#mainblock > div")` = the childs only level

`$("#mainblock  div")` = all the childs+ desendents.

Comment: If the node you're looking for is a parent of mainblock, better to use >.  Aside from being more precise, it's also faster.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at jQuery [**Selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

[`Child Selector ("parent > child")`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) -
Hierarchy Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

[`Descendant Selector ("ancestor descendant")`-](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)
Hierarchy Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#mainblock div")
```

This one target all DIVs inside "#mainblock" not matter it's direct child of "#mainblock", or child of child of main block or so on.

```
$("#mainblock > div")
```

This will target only direct child DIVs of "#mainblock" and ignore other DIVs. This one is faster then above in case you have only direct childs. Because it's not try to find inside other elements of childs.

Answer (score 4):

$("#mainblock div") find all the divs under #mainblock

$("#mainblock > div") only found its child

suppose you have below HTML structure:

```
    <div id="mainblock"> 
      <div>
        <div></div> 
        <div></div>
      </div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
   </div>
```

Then

```
$("#mainblock div").length = 5
$("#mainblock > div").length = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

The first one will get all `div`s descendant of `#mainblock`. The second one will get all `div`s that are immediate children of `#mainblock`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#mainblock div")
```

Matches any div element that is a descendant of #mainblock.

```
$("#mainblock > div")
```

Matches any div element that is a child of #mainblock .

check http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 1):

The first one will select any div that is a child of `#mainblock' at any level. The second will select any div that is an immediate child.

See this [link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector) for more info on the CSS `>` selector which behaves the same as in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).