# In cypress testing how to use value of a selector partially?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, cypress

So I have these selectors:

```
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > abc-51 > xyz')
cy.get(':nth-child(2) > abc-51 > xyz')
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > abc-51 > xyz')
```

How do I only use `cy.get(':nth-child(1)')` or `cy.get(':nth-child(2)')` instead of whole thing because the issue is `abc-51` keeps changing like it will become `abc-43`, etc. so tests keeps on failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each section of the selector is a different element level, and having `>` between them means "parent-child" relationship.

But if you omit `>` and just use a space between selectors, it should still work as you now have "parent-grandchild" (in your case), or generally a "parent-descendent" relationship.

So, just use this as your partial selector:

```js
cy.get(':nth-child(1) xyz')
```

Here is another question for reference:
[What is the difference direct descendent (>) vs. descendant in jQuery selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223143/what-is-the-difference-direct-descendent-vs-descendant-in-jquery-selectors)

---

Note you can also use Cypress `.find()` to do a descendent search:

```js
cy.get(':nth-child(1)').find('xyz')
```

Answer (score 2):

[Adding `^` in your selector will match on selectors that begin with that value.](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_attr_begin.php) In your example, the following should work:

```js
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > [whatever-attribute^="abc-"] > xyz');
```

Comment: how do I use `^` if there's no attribute? In my case it's exactly like `cy.get(':nth-child(1) > abc-51 > xyz')`